# how to count maximum duplicate cell on the behalf of date in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am developing a web application for message sending.
I have the following columns: `TO,MSG,DATE,FROM`.
I want to count maximum msg sender on the basis date.
Then what should be a sql query here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select top 1 form ,Date, count(1) MsgCount
From 
group by form ,Date
order by 3 desc`

this will return 1 row with maximum msg sender details if u remove top 1 you will get all users in the order of msg send :)

Comment: Is this query for single/particular date? What will happen in more than one date scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope this what you expected,

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE ([TO] varchar(20),MSG varchar(50),[Date] DATETIME,[From] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES
                  ('Person1','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender1'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender1'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE()-1,'Sender1'),
                  ('Person3','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender1'),
                  ('Person4','Msg',GETDATE()-1,'Sender1'),
                  ('Person5','Msg',GETDATE()-2,'Sender1'),
                  ('Person6','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender1'),
                  ('Person3','Msg',GETDATE()-1,'Sender1'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender1'),
                  ('Person1','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender2'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender2'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE()-1,'Sender2'),
                  ('Person3','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender3'),
                  ('Person4','Msg',GETDATE()-1,'Sender3'),
                  ('Person5','Msg',GETDATE()-2,'Sender3'),
                  ('Person6','Msg',GETDATE(),'Sender3'),
                  ('Person3','Msg',GETDATE()-5,'Sender2'),
                  ('Person2','Msg',GETDATE()-4,'Sender2')
SELECT
    [Date]
    ,[SentCount]
    ,[From]
FROM

    select
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(varchar(10),[DATE],103) ORDER BY COUNT([From]) DESC) AS [RANK],
        [From],
        COUNT([From]) AS [SentCount],
        CONVERT(varchar(10),[DATE],103) AS [Date]
    FROM 
        @Temp 
    GROUP BY [From],CONVERT(varchar(10),[DATE],103) 
) A
WHERE
    [Rank]=1
```